# How to manage a fork error potentially caused by BLODA in Cygwin?

Tags: python, windows, package, cygwin

I'm encountering a fork error (see below) as I install project requirements from a `requirements.txt` file with `pip` in Cygwin. I realize the best way to install packages in Cygwin is with the startup .exe, but a number of the files I'm looking to use (or the needed versions) are not in the Cygwin package list (i.e. Flask).

I am aware that [BLODA](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda) could be causing this fork issue as I have both Avast and an NVIDIA GeForce graphics card - both of which are on the [list](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda) of ware that can cause problems. I turned off the Filesystem and Behavior components of Avast (as recommended) but still experienced the problem. How would I work around the NVIDIA GeForce driver? I could hook up to the native graphics card, but does that circumvent the problem since it doesn't actually remove the driver? I've found it hard to discover detailed approaches to addressing this. Has anyone found a way around this?

```
0 [main] python2.7 1731 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'libpython2.7.dll' (0x400000) is already occupied
Error [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable while executing command python setup.py egg_info
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @Chris J. Breisch below for suggesting what is probably the best approach in most cases - to rebase all my packages. Alas, because I'm working with an older project requiring older packages (and some like Flask that appear not to be included in Cygwin at all) rebasing is not on the table for me. It may be that I have to abandon Cygwin and use a different approach given my current constraints.

**UPDATE:** I went ahead and tried @Chris J. Breisch's suggested rebase; however, I still experienced the same fork error in the same place after rebasing.

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot is this section from the Cygwin [FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq.html).

[How do I fix fork() failures?](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures)

Most likely the tip you want is this:

> Force a full rebase: Run `rebase-trigger fullrebase`, exit all Cygwin programs and run Cygwin setup.
>
> By default, Cygwin's setup program automatically performs an incremental rebase of newly installed files. Forcing a full rebase causes the rebase map to be cleared before doing the rebase.
>
> See /usr/share/doc/rebase/README and /usr/share/doc/Cygwin/_autorebase.README for more details.
>
> Please note that installing new packages or updating existing ones undoes the effects of rebase and often causes fork() failures to reappear.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and response! Yeah, because I'm working with older packages for an older project, rebasing isn't going to work for now. I think I'm giving up on Cygwin and moving to an approach based on the native command prompt.

Comment: You should be able to do a rebase no matter what versions of the packages you're using. Running setup will tell you if you have anything that's out of date, but you don't have to upgrade. Just deselect whatever it wants you to upgrade. The important bit is just getting to the end of the setup where it does the rebaseall.

Comment: I just did the rebasing and then tried loading my requirements afterward. It still crashed with a fork error in the same place. This case seems to require another approach. Regardless - thanks for the attempt!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it wasn't more useful. I really expected that to work. It's nearly always worked for me when I've had fork() issues. Good luck with your next attempt. If you're going with regular Windows things, I'd recommend PowerShell, but there's a little bit of a learning curve to using PS correctly.

Comment: Yeah, thanks again. That's where I'm headed - getting a start with Powershell. Already much further, though as you say, a bit of a learning curve.